# SQL: Join to different table based on column data

Tags: sql

My scenario are as below:

Table: t_audit

```
row | colname | oldvalue | newvalue
===================================
1   | locid   | 001      | 002
2   | typeid  | 010      | 011
```

Table: t_ref_audit

```
colname | desc        | link_table  | link_key  | link_desc
===========================================================
locid   | Location    | t_ref_loc   | locid     | loc_desc
typeid  | Type        | t_ref_type  | typeid    | type_desc
```

Table: t_ref_loc

```
locid | type_desc
==================
001   | LOCATION A
002   | LOCATION B
```

Table: t_ref_type

```
typeid | loc_desc
==================
010   | TYPE C
011   | TYPE D
```

As you can see from above, the first table is my audit log table, and 2nd table is the reference table. 3rd and 4th tables are reference tables. By using simple SQL below I can get the proper description for the column name based on t_ref_audit table.

```
SELECT t_ref_audit.desc, t_audit.oldvalue, t_audit.newvalue
FROM t_audit, t_ref_audit
WHERE t_audit.colname = t_ref_audit.colname
```

My problem now is, the columns on t_audit.oldvalue and t_audit.newvalue contains reference code ID from other reference tables (t_ref_loc & t_ref_type). I wanted to show the proper description based on columns from t_ref_audit.link_desc instead of just the ID as below:

```
coldesc  | oldvalue   | newvalue
==================================
Location | LOCATION A | LOCATION B
Type     | TYPE C     | TYPE D
```

Hope someone can enlighten me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried somthing so far??

Comment: Unrelated but: you should stop using the outdated implicit join syntax in the `where` clause. Use an explicit `JOIN` operator instead.

Comment: I did tried before but so far can't think of any method to join the table which is the value inside another table.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? (and the same logic for newvalues...)

```
SELECT
  t_ref_audit.desc,
  t_audit.oldvalue,
  t_audit.newvalue,
  case
    when link_table='t_ref_loc' then t_ref_loc.loc_desc
    when link_table='t_ref_type' then t_ref_type.type_desc
    else '???'
  end oldvalue_desc
FROM
  t_audit
  join t_ref_audit ON t_audit.colname = t_ref_audit.colname
  left join t_ref_loc on link_table='t_ref_loc' and oldvalue=locid
  left join t_ref_type on link_table='t_ref_type' and oldvalue=typeid
```

- The logic works only for static mapping...
- I think you mixed a bit t_ref_loc/t_ref_type tables and their titles.

Comment: Yeah, short of writing stored procedures or other code a simple left join seems like the way to go.  +1!

Comment: Yes.. thanks for highlighting about the wrong field name. In my actual case I have more than 30 reference tables to be linked. Unless I hardcoded all the linked tables inside case statement like your sample then should be no problem. Thanks for your help.